# Translating plain English to a (conditional) probability

Tags: probability

I have no difficulty thinking in mathematical notation, e.g., the interpretations of $P(x|y)$, $P(y|x)$, $P(x \cap y)$, etc. are all clear to me. However, once I start putting these concepts into words, things become muddier.

Imagine I just took the picture of a animal footprint ($F$) in the forest. It could be that of a coyote ($C$), or that of a feral dog ($D$)---but I'm not sure. I take the picture to an expert and he says that the footprint has a probability $P_d$ of being that of a dog and $P_c$ of being that of a coyote. How should I interpret these probabilities? Should $P_c$ be equivalent to $P(F|C)$, or $P(C|F)$, or maybe even $P(C \cap F)$? Please motivate your answer, because the direction of the *"given that"* is really not obvious at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're determining is the probability of the animal being a coyote. The evidence you have (which will impact this probability) is the footprint. Therefore you have that $$P_c = P(C|F)$$ that is, $P_c$ is the probability that the animal is a coyote, given the footprint that you saw. The evidence that you have is always the thing that follows the $|$ sign, because that is what is "given." I'm unsure if this is enough "motivation" let me know if it helps.

Comment: I understand the notation. The problem is with the order: We might as well have considered the "prerequisite" to be the animal who _generated_ the footprint, in which case $P_c = P(F|C)$ would make more sense. The more I think about the problem, the fuzzier is the distinction between $P(F|C)$ and $P(C|F)$.

Comment: Right, but you have not observed information about the animal. So it can't be given the type of animal. The "given" is the event that you've already observed and known to be true.